# Can we inject properties of a class with certain pre-define values in spring using autowire?

Tags: java, spring

assume there is a class Person

```
class Person{
   
private Address add;

}

class Address{
   String street;
}
```

The moment I create a bean of Person class then I need a person bean to have address property with value street as "baker lane". Is it possible to use autowire in Person class to achieve this or it cannot be achieved at all?

This was an interview question by the way

Comment: Autowiring is meant for _service objects_, which define the structure of the application, not _data objects_, which are different for each operation. `Person` and `Address` should not normally be managed beans.

Comment: You can mark your Address class bean and load a value of street with @value and mark Address variable in person class as AutoWired

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autowiring on your constructor and modify the behavior of person.

Your interviewer probably expected the following to be explained

```
@Component
class Person{

  private Address add;
   
  @Autowired
  public Person(Address add) {    <--- An instance of Address will be injected here
  this.add = add;
  
 //this.add.setStreet("Custom Street");  <--- you can modify that here before the Autowiring constructor ends
  
  /* if (add.getStreet().isEmpty()) {   <--- you can do whatever you want inside the constructor
      add.setStreet("Should not be empty") <--- you can check conditionally and set everything you want
   } */

  }

}

@Component
class Address{
   String street;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can set default value in Spring expression

**#{expression?:default value}**

```
//set deafult value for street

@Value("#{address.street ?: 'baker lane'}")
private String street;
```